# CodeVision AVR send and receive USART data

Tags: c, microcontroller

I am trying to receive and send data using USART communication, i use atmega16. I created program in PC to send string to micro, if the string is match, micro will activate adc and send adc data's to PC.

this is code in my microcontroler

```
#include <mega16.h>
#include <delay.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ADC_VREF_TYPE 0xC0

unsigned int read_adc(unsigned char pin_adc)
{
ADMUX=pin_adc | ADC_VREF_TYPE;
// Delay needed for the stabilization of the ADC input voltage
delay_us(10);
// Start the AD conversion
ADCSRA|=0x40;
// Wait for the AD conversion to complete
while ((ADCSRA & 0x10)==0);
ADCSRA|=0x10;
return ADCW;
}

//unsigned char DataInput = 0x00;
unsigned long int osilator = 12000000;
unsigned long int UBRR;
unsigned int t0, t1, t2, t3;
float t00, t11, t22, t33;

void inisialisasiUART(unsigned long int baud_rate);
//unsigned char getData(void);

unsigned char compare[30] = "a";
unsigned char input[30];
unsigned char buf[30];
void main(void)
{
    ADMUX = ADC_VREF_TYPE;
    ADCSRA = 0x85;
    inisialisasiUART(9600);
    while(1)
    {               
        //DataInput = getData();  

        scanf("%s", input);  
        if(strcmp(input, compare) == 0)
        {   
            t0 = read_adc(0);  
            t00 = (float)t0*256/1024; 

            t1 = read_adc(1);         
            t11 = (float)t0*256/1024;  

            t2 = read_adc(2);          
            t22 = (float)t0*256/1024;  

            t3 = read_adc(3);      
            t33 = (float)t0*256/1024;  

            sprintf(buf, "a%.2f %.2f %.2f %.2fa", t00, t11, t22, t33);   
            printf("%s", buf);
        }   
    }
}

void inisialisasiUART(unsigned long int baud_rate)
{
    UBRR  = (osilator/(16*baud_rate))-1;
    UBRRL = UBRR;
    UBRRH = UBRR>>8;
    UCSRB = 0x18;
    UCSRC = 0x86;
}

unsigned char getData(void)
{
while(!(UCSRA & 0x80));
return UDR;
}
```

From my code, where is the mistake? Do i can using scanf to receive usart data? And what the best way to receive and send data? using UDR or printf scanf?
thank you

Comment: If you put say `printf("Hello");` after `inisialisasiUART` do you get any output on the PC?

Comment: i dont get sir. i use device monitoring studio for monitoring serial port data packet, request etc. And in tab request view, if i send example char 'a' to microcontroller, buffer size become 1bytes, then i send again char 'a', buffer size become 2bytes. So my micro not read data from pc sir?

Answer (score 0):

Well you could use strncmp() but personally I'd be using strstr() which I prefer when it comes to "parsing" responses.

Answer (score -2):

```
enter code here
include<stdlib.h>  
char str2[40];
float dist_klimeter;
dist_klimeter=cust5_distance/1000.00;
ftoa(dist_klimeter, 2, str2);
sprintf(string, "  d:%sKm" ,  str2);
```

Comment: Can you please add some explenation to your answer? Simply showing code can be confusing for some people.